'http_request_duration_seconds_count disappear' in Prometheus Metric by default
I deployed Grafana with Prometheus.
I aim to monitor all api call requests of apps in seperated namespace.
But I cannot found http_request_duration_seconds_count in Metrics browser by default.

I dont know the root cause and could you please help teach how to configure 'http_request_duration_seconds_count' / 'http_request_duration_seconds_sum' / 'http_request_duration_seconds_bucket' on Prometheus?

Prometheus scrapes metrics from exporters. This dropdown only shows metrics that were scraped. Do you have a target in your Prometheus that exposes those metrics you want to use?

It seems I need to configure scrape_config for 'http_request_duration_seconds_count'.
But I cannot find exampes for this scrapes metrics.

You don't configure scrape_config for 'http_request_duration_seconds_count'. You configure scrape of targe or targets. And if your target exposes that metric, prometheus will have it.

prometheus-node-exporter was already installed.

you said "configure scrape of targe or targets".
Does targets means "prometheus-node-exporter" or the target apps which I want to monitor?

Depends on what you intend to monitor. Based on your question, I'd guess you need to add your app first of all.
